# In a hello world flask application, using https instead of http introduces 1s overhead

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, https, azure-web-app-service, gunicorn

I created a simple app (flask + gunicorn) and uploaded it to Google App Engine to test how fast my request would be processed in a production environment. I was surprised to see a huge 0.7 to 1.2 second overhead introduced by using an http URL vs http**s** one (cold request was even slower). Is this normal or am I doing something wrong here.

I also tested my app in Azure App Service; I could not get http to work, but https request (which I'm interested in) resulted in a similar lag.

main.py (server side)

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_request():
    payload = request.json
    return payload
```

test.py (client side)

```
import requests
import time

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://name.appspot.com"

    def send_request(self, **kwargs):
        response = requests.post(self.url, json=kwargs)
        return(response.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    text = "Hi"
    start = time.time()
    result = test.send_request(text=text)
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Retrieved {result} in {end - start}')
```

Here are my config files for Google App Engine and Azure App Service.

Google (app.yaml):

```
runtime: python311
instance_class: F1
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

Azure (startup.txt)

```
gunicorn -w 4 main:app
```

Comment: Is it working fine locally?

Comment: it does, but it feels rather slow

Comment: @PravallikaKV I tried to test it today again, but apparently the local flask server does not support https to compare it with http.

Comment: I did a test, and instead of running the test locally on my computer. I run it on the server. Now everything is fine. Https requests are served in less than 0.1 s. What could be the reason. I have a fast connection with minimal lags.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of HTTPS depends on various factors like hardware, software, network, content, and caching of the web server and the client.

Azure App Service requires https by default as it is more secure protocol, and the lag could be due to additional processing required to establish a secure connection.

To improve the performance of your Python app in Azure Functions:

1. Reduce the overhead by using a faster SSL implementation or by optimizing your code.
2. Try horizontal scaling, which creates instances based on the load of your app and throughput performance configurations. Also upgrade to a premium plan to get more processing units.
3. Optimize your code in a more efficient data format to reduce the amount of data that needs to be transferred over the network.
4. Customize the **gunicorn configuration** by using a `gunicorn.conf.py file`.
5. The difference in performance while running locally and on the server could also be due to the network latency.

**References:**

[Running Your Flask Application Over HTTPS - miguelgrinberg.com](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https)